# How can I sort the items in dynamic created selection / option box in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, html-select

I am working on a private project, I have managed to create a combo listboxes that can add items from listboxA to go listboxB and from b to a, but I want the items in both list box to be ordered alphabetically whenever I add or remove. I want to also add a text field that I can type a profession and add to listbox b, any help will be greatly appreciated!

```js
$(function() {
  $("#but1").click(function() {
    $("#listbox1 option:selected").each(function() {
      $(this).remove().appendTo("#listbox2");
    });
  });
  $("#but2").click(function() {
    $("#listbox2 option:selected").each(function() {
      $(this).remove().appendTo("#listbox1");

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3 py-0 px-2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Select Skills</label>
    <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="listbox1">
      <option>A Skills A</option>
      <option>B Skills B</option>
      <option>C Skills c</option>
      <option>D Skills D</option>
      <option>E Skills E</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-1 pt-4">
  <div style="row">
    <span class="align-middle">
              <div style="text-align: center;">
                  <button id="but1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"> >> </button>
              </div>
         </span>
    <span class="align-middle">
              <div style="text-align: center;">
                  <button id="but2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"> << </button>
              </div>
                            
        </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 py-0 px-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Mechanic Skills</label>
    <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="listbox2" name="mechskills">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not able to get your code to work. It seems some pieces are missing.

Comment: For sorting you'll need to take your professions list out of HTML to JS and store it in array. Than you can re-sort your array using Array.sort() method after any change and rebuild the select with new items order.

Comment: Regarding textbox to search profession by its name, this is called "autocomplete" and you may consider using [jQuryUI Autocomple](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) for this

Comment: I want to have sorting on both listbox1 and listbox 2 and I want to have another input group of one text field with a button that says add this will enable me to input a cutom text to listbox2

Comment: Please take a look at that denis

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would take to do this would be to move the skills to the JavaScript code so that it is easier to manage the sort order. If we have our array of skills sorted to begin with, we can use an object to keep track of which skills are selected and which are not. Then, when we render our lists, we iterate through the list of skills (that is already sorted) and determine which skill goes to which box based on the value in the selection object map.

```js
$(function() {
  const skills = [
    'A Skills A',
    'B Skills B',
    'C Skills C',
    'D Skills D',
    'E Skills E'
  ];
  
  const skillSelectionMap = {};
  
  const render = () => {
    const selectedSkills = skills.filter(skill => skillSelectionMap[skill]);
    const unselectedSkills = skills.filter(skill => !skillSelectionMap[skill]);
  
    $('#listbox1').html(unselectedSkills.map(skill => `<option>${skill}</option>`).join(''));
    $('#listbox2').html(selectedSkills.map(skill => `<option>${skill}</option>`).join(''));
 };
 
    
  
  $("#but1").click(function() {
    $("#listbox1 option:selected").each(function() {
      const skill = $(this).val();
      
      skillSelectionMap[skill] = true;
      render();
    });
  });
  
  $("#but2").click(function() {
    $("#listbox2 option:selected").each(function() {
      const skill = $(this).val();
      
      skillSelectionMap[skill] = false;
      render();
    });
  });
  
  render();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3 py-0 px-2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Select Skills</label>
    <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="listbox1"></select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-1 pt-4">
  <div style="row">
    <span class="align-middle">
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <button id="but1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"> >> </button>
      </div>
    </span>
    <span class="align-middle">
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <button id="but2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
          << </button>
      </div>

    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 py-0 px-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Mechanic Skills</label>
    <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="listbox2" name="mechskills">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh thanks let me test this... Thank you Dennis!

Comment: @gratitudetags If this was helpful to you, I would appreciate you marking it as the accepted answer.